# how to remove all event onlick of Jquery

Tags: jquery

When i click in input event dropdown is actived. Now i wanna click outside it and all event of dropdown is removed.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" class=" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I use this code below but it not work .Everybody help me

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
        $(this).find("*").off('click');
    });
```

Comment: I see no Javascript here. It's not clear what events you're referring to, can you post the code?

Comment: window.addEventListener("click", () => {
        $(this).find("*").off('click');
    });

Comment: I use off(), unblind() but almost not working the code i had used it above

Comment: If you want to use `this`, don't use an arrow function - calling context will not be captured

Comment: i fix code to fuction() but it stilling not work                                                               window.addEventListener("click", function(){  
                          $(this).find("*").off('click');
                         });

Comment: I don't know why in fuction it not work although it call addEventListener success

Comment: If you can write that event pls help me as code write javascript

Comment: It event i wanna remove is 2 tag input have data-toggle="dropdown"

Comment: change the event listener callback to `window.addEventListener("click", function(){
        $(this).find("*").off('click');
    });`

Comment: you can give example bro. I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
 // onclick of dropdown add click class event
 $('.dropdown').click(function(){
    $(this).find('drop-down-toggle').addClass('click');
 });

// onclick of html remove all click class from drop down toggle
$('html').click(function(){
    $('.drop-down-toggle').removeClass('click');  
 });
```